# make/Makefile: CLI option to "disable" a dependency from a target

Tags: makefile

I'm exploring a feature of some software that's used in a very mature Makefile to see if that feature can be incorporated into the flow. There is a target like the following:

```
my_target: dependency_1 dependency_2
        echo foo
        touch bar
        # etc...
```

In regular use, dependency_2 would always be called before my_target's commands were executed. But for my exploration purposes, I want to selectively call dependency_2 from its own make command. And then make my_target after, possibly several times, without re-doing dependency_2 each time.

For the time being I just copy/pasted my_target into my_target_2 and removed the dependency from my_target_2 (easy enough), but I'm wondering if there's a command-line option to disable a target's dependency without modifying the file.

EDIT: dependency_2 is a PHONY target

Comment: Is `dependency_2` a PHONY target, or the name of a file that is actually built?

Comment: Oops my bad - should have specified that. It's a PHONY target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But for my exploration purposes, I want to selectively call dependency_2 from its own make command

This is done as easy as `make dependency_2`

> And then make my_target after, possibly several times, without re-doing dependency_2 each time

Normally, dependency_2 should be a file on the disk, so make would skip rebuilding it until its own prerequisites (source files) are changed.

But if dependency_2 is a .PHONY target ("fake file"), it **will** be rebuilt on each run. In this case you still can fool it like this:

```
echo "dependency_2:;@:" | make -f Makefile -f -
```

However, make will issue a warning about overriding a recipe for dependency_2.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that dependency_2 is a PHONY target. I'm having a hard time understanding what your "fooling" command is doing.

Comment: .PHONY is a separate attribute and won't be "undone" by redefining the rule.

Comment: @MadScientist Sure, but in this particular case OP **wants** to run the recipe of my_target. Just forcefully skipping the recipe of dependency_2.

Comment: @PistoletPierre It effectively cancels all commands for building dependency_2 (or to put it in other words, it says that the process of building dependency_2 consists of an empty command). Without dropping dependency_2 itself.

Comment: @PistoletPierre This could have some side-effects though. Say, if there's a "pure dependency rule" (i.e. without a recipe attached), such as `dependency_2: dependency_3` then the recipe for `dependency_3` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this without editing the makefile, that I can think of.

You can put `dependency_2` into a variable then use the variable in the prerequisite list of `my_target`:

```
dependency_2 = dependency_2

my_target : dependency_1 $(dependency_2)
```

then when you don't want to rebuild it, run `make dependency_2=` to reset the variable to empty.